# jQuery- .load() more divs with embedded youtube videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I have a Videos page on my website that has numerous divs that have embedded youtube videos with titles, descriptions, etc..

How can I make it so that it only shows the first 3 divs and then load an additional three for every click on a "load more" button.

I've already tried hiding all the divs and then .show()ing the first three and then showing the next three with each click BUT for some reason with embedded videos or perhaps iframes you can't actually see them when you "show()" them.  Only the other html elements actually appear.

Here was my failed attempt:

```
$(function(){
            $("div").slice(0, 3).show(); // select the first three
            $("#load").click(function(e){ // click event for load more
                e.preventDefault();
                $("div:hidden").slice(0, 3).show(); // select next 3 hidden divs and show them
                if($("div:hidden").length == 0){ // check if any hidden divs still exist
                    alert("No more divs"); // alert if there are none left
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Try also adding a css property on each of the one's that you are showing like so
`$('.exampleVideoEl').css('z-index', '10000');`  This might bring them back to the front.

Answer (score 0):

Using show/hide toggles the div's `display:` attribute between `display:block` an `display:none`.  When using `display:none`, the element isn't rendered (nor is the video loaded).  You could use `visibility: hidden` instead or possibly absolutely position the "hidden" divs offscreen with something like `position:absolute; top:-9999px` and then moving them back upon clicking the "load more" button.